in Dearpygui's demo, I want to know the underlying code of the 'Metrics' option。
I'm aiming to create a GUI for real-time plotting of curves. During my learning process, I noticed there's a 'Metrics' section in the demo.py provided by Dear PyGui, which allows real-time monitoring of GPU and CPU (as shown in the figure). This aligns with my goals, so I'm curious about how it's achieved. Could you provide insights into this?
·······

with dpg.menu(label="Tools"):

            dpg.add_menu_item(label="Show About", callback=lambda:dpg.show_tool(dpg.mvTool_About))
            dpg.add_menu_item(label="Show Metrics", callback=lambda:dpg.show_tool(dpg.mvTool_Metrics))
            dpg.add_menu_item(label="Show Documentation", callback=lambda:dpg.show_tool(dpg.mvTool_Doc))
            dpg.add_menu_item(label="Show Debug", callback=lambda:dpg.show_tool(dpg.mvTool_Debug))
            dpg.add_menu_item(label="Show Style Editor", callback=lambda:dpg.show_tool(dpg.mvTool_Style))
            dpg.add_menu_item(label="Show Font Manager", callback=lambda:dpg.show_tool(dpg.mvTool_Font))
            dpg.add_menu_item(label="Show Item Registry", callback=lambda:dpg.show_tool(dpg.mvTool_ItemRegistry))


a very interesting question, you might want to start with the docs here:  https://pypi.org/project/dearpygui/1.4.0
